# Describe the topology generated by a set

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a subset of $X$. I want to define a topology of $A$ called $\sigma(A)$ such that every element of $A$ is in $\sigma(A)$. I thought the following:

$B = \{C \in \mathcal{P}(X) / C=\cap A_i$ with $A_i \in A\}$

$\sigma(A) = \{U \in \mathcal{P}(X) / C=\cup B_i$ with $B_i \in B\}$

It wasn't hard to prove that $\varnothing, A \in \sigma(A)$ and $\cup U_i \in \sigma(A)$. But I'm not finding a way to prove that $U \cap V \in \sigma(A)$ if $U,V \in \sigma(A)$.

Comment: I would use \$\mid\$ or : to write the delimiter in set-builder notation, as $\mathcal P(X)/C$ looks like a quotient set. Other than that, it is unclear where your intersections / unions range over. Do the $A_i$ or $B_i$ make up a finite part, or an infinite part of the sets in $A$ or $B$?

Comment: Should $A$ be a subset of $\mathcal{P}(X)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sigma(A)$ is the smallest topology on $X$ such that $A\subset\sigma(A)$, then $A$ is called a [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase) for the topology on $X$.

First, a topology should be closed under **finite** intersections. Therefore, if $A$ is not closed under finite intersections, we should first do so. This is probably what you tried to do with your set $B$, but as the range of indices is not clear from your definition, it is not clear whether you mean finite intersections or arbitrary intersections.

I would define $B$ as follows:

> $B:=\left\{C\in\mathcal P(X)\mid \exists C'\subset A\ (\ C=\bigcap C'\text{ and $C'$ is finite}\ )\ \right\}$

Here I also use that the intersection of nothing is equal to everything, that is, $\bigcap \varnothing=X$. This is important to be able to show that $X$ is in the topology. If you disagree with this use of empty intersection, you could remedy this by adding $X$ to $B$.

The set $B$ that I now have, is a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) for the topology $\sigma(A)$. We can now define $\sigma(A)$ by closing $B$ under arbitrary unions:

> $\sigma(A):=\left\{C\in\mathcal P(X)\mid \exists C'\subset B\ (\ C=\bigcup C'\ )\ \right\}$

Note that here it is not specified how many sets of $B$ are in the union. Similar to with the definition of $B$, I use that the union of nothing is equal to nothing, that is, $\bigcup \varnothing=\varnothing$. Alternatively, if this bothers you, you could simply add $\varnothing$ afterwards.

---

The proof that $\varnothing\in\sigma(A)$ is done by using an empty union. Since $X\in B$ by using an empty intersection, we have that $X\in\sigma(A)$ as well (Note that you said you proved "$A\in\sigma(A)$"; this is not correct, we need $X\in\sigma(A)$ as well. Actually $A\in\sigma(A)$ usually makes no sense, since $A$ is a set of subsets of $X$, and a set of subsets of $X$ does not have to be a subset of $X$ itself).

To show that $\sigma(A)$ is closed under arbitrary unions is trivial from its definition.

Finally, if $U,V\in\sigma(A)$, then let $C_U,C_V\subset B$ be such that $U=\bigcup C_U$ and $V=\bigcup C_V$. Then $$U\cap V=\bigcup C_U\cap \bigcup C_V=\bigcup_{c_U\in C_U\,\land\, c_V\in C_V} c_U\cap c_V.$$

The last equality follows from the infinite distributive law $X\cap \bigcup Y_i=\bigcup (X\cap Y_i)$. For each $c_U\in C_U$ and $c_V\in C_V$ we have $c_U,c_V\in B$, and thus the finite intersection $c_U\cap c_V\in B$ by how we defined $B$. Therefore $U\cap V$ is a union of elements of $B$, giving $U\cap V\in \sigma(A)$.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to clear some things a little more, just to be sure. 

In the definition of $B$, with $C'$ finite, did you meant to say that is intersection of finite sets $C'$?

Instead of $A \in \sigma(A)$ I should've put $A \subset \sigma(A)$, right?

Comment: No, the sets inside $C'$ could be finite or infinite. The size of $C'$ itself must be finite. There can be at most finitely many sets that you take the intersection over. As an example, consider the **cofinite topology** on $\Bbb N$, that is, the topology of all sets $A\subseteq \Bbb N$ such that $\Bbb N\setminus A$ is finite. If you take a finite intersection of cofinite sets, then the result is cofinite, thus the topology is closed under finite intersections. However, if you take the intersection of infinitely many cofinite sets, the result will no longer be cofinite.

Comment: Indeed, $A\subset \sigma(A)$ makes sense, since "every element of $A$ is in $\sigma(A)$" was the goal of this whole thing. Whether or not $A\subset\sigma(A)$ does not really matter in the proof that $\sigma(A)$ is a topology, it matters only to show that $\sigma(A)$ is indeed a topology containing $A$. If you want, you could show that $\sigma(A)$ is indeed the *smallest* topology such that $A\subset\sigma(A)$, as leaving out any set from $\sigma(A)$ that is not in $A$ will break the topology.